# Json post with multi parameter to WebApi vs MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We are moving from MVC to WepApi to serve our data. Here is the sample of how we have changed out controller.

MVC:

```
OfficeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> SetSalary(string badge, string salary)
    {
        return new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

WebApi

```
OfficeApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> SetSalary(string badge, string salary)
    {
        return new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

We are sending the data from client with something like following:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ badge: '123', salary: '100000' });
// MVC
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    url: 'Office/SetSalary',
});

// WebApi
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   url: 'ActionApi/OfficeApi/SetSalary',
});
```

The MVC controller works fine; however for webapi we are getting the following message:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'OfficeApiController ' that matches the request."}
```

If our post has ONLY ONE parameter then everything is working fine with WebApi

If we put the badge and salary in a class and change the post parameter to that class then everything is working fine.

If we submit them as two parameters but in a webform then everything works fine.

The webapi only fails when we submit Json and the controller have two parameter instead of a single class with those parameters as property.

We know the WebApi is meant for Rest and it should get/pot/delete/update one resource but I cant figure out why it can not parse two Json parameter.

Please note this is not our actual code and a simplified version to ask questions. There might be some typo but everything complies and run fine in our test.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of the box, Web API doesn't support multiple parameters in the POST body.  The typical solution is to wrap it into a single class.  It can be done the other way, but AFAIK, you need to override the default HttpParameterBinding.

Comment: can you try sending the parameters in the url itself for the webapi? ActionApi/OfficeApi/SetSalary/{badge}/{salary}

Answer (score 2):

**WebAPI** supports only **one parameter** sent via POST. This is OK, because you can wrap everything in an **object**.

In your jQuery `$.ajax` post, you are actually already sending one parameter.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ badge: '123', salary: '100000' });
```

This creates an object, with two properties, `badge` and `salary`.

You need to change your WebAPI code to something like

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Employee> SetSalary([FromBody]SalaryData data)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Then have a `SalaryData` class declared like

```
public class SalaryData
{
    public string Badge {set; get;}
    public string Salary {set; get;}
}
```